# gmail api: wrong results getting messages with a specific label

Tags: java, email, gmail-api

I am trying to get all the messages with a specific label.
A test code I am using is the same in the gmail api documentation:

```
ListMessagesResponse response = service.users().messages().list(userId)
        .setLabelIds(labelIds).execute();

List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
while (response.getMessages() != null) {
    messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
    if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
        String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
        response = service.users().messages().list(userId).setLabelIds(labelIds)
                .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

log.info("num messages: {}", messages.size());
```

The problem is that the number of messages I get is much less that the number of messages that I see on gmail web selecting this label.
For example there is a conversation with more than 10 messages and I get just one.

I was thinking that listing the messages with a specific label using gmail api returns me all the messages with this label: like all the messages you see in the web interface when you select this label.

If this can help, the messages I am trying to get have more than one label.

Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:

After some tests I decide to try to search for threads with a specific label instead of messages and once I have the threads with this label I get all the messages in every thread.

The fact that I noted is that if a thread has a label NOT all the messages in the thread are marked with this label and this is why, imho, my fist attempt to get all the messages with a specific label fails: they differ.

Why the messages in a thread marked with a label are not all marked with the same label?

Comment: Infact now I am working on getting threads with a specific label and then all the messages of the threads. It seems the right way

Comment: yes, you're in the right path.

Answer (score 0):

When you said "there is a conversation with more than 10 messages and I get just one."  What you got was 1 Message Thread not 10 individual messages. It could be that that those conversations belonged to 1 thread only. Check the [Managing Threads](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/threads) and [Managing Labels](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels).